# How to rewrite it more efficiently (linq with split)?

Tags: linq, simplify

here is the problem:
I have a column with the topics in the format: "boston | new york | chicago". The names can be different and number of the topics can vary in the records. 
What I need to come up with is the collection of the same names with the count of those names.

This is what I have done:

```
 var splitted = queryResult.Select(x => x.TopicData);
 List<string> lstOfTopics = new List<string>();
 foreach (var element in splitted)
 {
   string[] splitedTopics = element.Split('|');
   lstOfTopics.AddRange(splitedTopics);
 }
var groupedTopics = lstOfTopics.GroupBy(x => x).Select(group => new {key = group.Key, count = group.Count()}).AsEnumerable();
```

seems a lot of code for a simple task. any ideas how to simplify this?

thanks!

Comment: Do you need to trim the whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the list using `SelectMany` and `ToList`:

```
List<string> lstOfTopics = splitted.SelectMany(x => x.Split('|')).ToList();
```

You can also omit the construction of the list entirely:

```
var groupedTopics = queryResult
    .SelectMany(x => x.TopicData.Split('|'))
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(group => new { group.Key, Count = group.Count()});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var groups = queryResult
  .SelectMany(t => t.TopicData.Split('|')
  .GroupBy(n => n)
  .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Answer (score 0):

query syntax can be nice and compact:

```
var topics =
    from qr in queryResult
    from topic in qr.TopicData.Split('|')
    group topic by topic into g
    select new { Topic = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

If you want just the unique topics, but not their counts...

```
List<string> topicList = topics.Select(item => item.Topic);
```